# No audit events generated although relevant SACLs are in place

Tags: windows, security, registry, acl, auditing

I want to monitor registry modifications from a given key and its subkeys and values by setting the relevant SACLs and consuming the [audit event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/auditing/event-4657).

I've set the SACL in place on the registry key and configured it to monitor all modification attempts from Everyone:

[Screen shot of ACE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H9Wv.png)

However, I've noticed that when a new value is created through the command line reg command, an auditing event will be generated:

```
reg add hklm\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TestService /v DeleteFlag /t REG_NONE /d 1
```

Although no event is being generated when the new key is created using C# code. For example:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TestService\");
key.SetValue("DeleteFlag", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
key.Close();
```

There is also no event when the event is not created directly by me. For example running "sc create" which writes to the registry:

```
sc create haithamtest2 binpath="c:\temp\123.exe"
```

Why is this happening? Any way to get these events?